# No foreign key constraints in database.!

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, hibernate-mapping

My organization works on Spring MVC with Hibernate. We always specify foreign key constraints in mapping file, like for person and contactList in `Person.hbm.xml`

```
<set name="ContactList">
  <key column="PersonId" foreign-key="Fk_Peson_Contact"/>
  <one-to-many class="Sample.Model.Contact"/>
</set>
```

This mapping will create one-to-many relationship between `Person` and `Contact`, and keep `PersonID` as foreign key column in the `Contact` table.

But, now organization has decided not to mention any kind of relationship in mapping file, means in above case `Person` mapping will not have any kind of one-to-many mapping instead of this `Contact` mapping will have property `<property name="FK_PersonID"/>` which will create column to hold `personID`. In this scenario table `Person` and `Contact` will look same but the difference is their is no relationship between `Person` and `Contact` coz no mapping is specified.

In such case if we want to fetch person's contactList then we have to fire two queries one to fetch person another for its contactList. let suppose we want to fetch personList with its contactList then we have to `For loop` on PersonList and fetch its ContactList which will fire number of queries.

When i ask why not specify relationship then senior said ,

- If foreign key is in DB then we can't do slicing and partitioning.
- When we fire join query DB takes more time to execute it.Which may slow down DB server.

But,my question is -

- if i do `For looping` on personList then it will fire number of queries to fetch contacts is it feasible?
- can such looping slow down application or application server?
- what if i want to fetch personList with its conatctList,AddressList,QualificationList, Does this cause n+1 issue?

**Which Scenario is more beneficial whether to specify mapping or not.**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I one of the early demos of partitioning in (MS) SQL by microsoft they showed a query which selected from a partioned table with data populated across several partions, and it used its indexes and stats to not even bother accessing partitions that had no (relevant) data. Of course if you dont have a fk constaint then it cant use the index and stats to know the fk conforms. I'd be fairly sure it would be covered by Kalen Delaney in her book (for the relevant version of MSSQL). The key is that the stats will contain the necessary information to prevent unnecessary seeks. The demo actually used a union to easily demo the effect.

Comment: How do you know Amogh is using SQL Server?

Comment: SQL is just a *query language*. It is **not** the name of a DBMS product. All RDBMS use SQL.

Comment: MySQL is a trade mark, Oracle is a trade mark, There is no specic trade mark tag. MS SQL is often abreviated to SQL. More often than not if a trademark is not specified MS SQL is understood. The author has not supported your point of view.

Comment: The term `SQL` is only used by Microsoft SQL Server users as a synonym for the actual DBMS product. No one else mistakes the name of a query language for the name of a DBMS product (and SO does have different tags for `SQL` and `SQL Server`). But you are right the author has not stated his/her DBMS yet.

Comment: If the original author clarifies the matter then fine - otherwise there is little evidence to support your claim that "no one else" uses SQL to refer to MS SQL: for example it is the 3rd hit on Google when you type SQL. This is really very off topic so I will not prolong this arcane thread anymore.

Comment: i am using MySQL.Which Scenario is more beneficial whether to specify mapping or not and can you clarify my questions stated in question.

Comment: If MySQL uses the same techniques as MSSQL (indexes and statisitics) to ensure redundant reads are elliminated, then yes it would be more beneficial to have fk's and partioning, but you'll have to find a MySQL expert to answer if it does. Sorry cant help more. Of course if you have an equivalent of profiler or can read disk activity, then you could set up a test accross 2 or 3 drives to see.